# How to create multiple pie charts with D3 from a single array with multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

I am learning how to use D3.js and I am trying to render multiple pie charts from JSON data that I fetched from an external API. The data that I am working with look like below

```
tickers = [{
    "symbol": "GME",
    "buy": 0,
    "hold": 3,
    "period": "2021-08-01",
    "sell": 5,
    "strongBuy": 0,
    "strongSell": 2
}, {
    "symbol": "AMD",
    "buy": 21,
    "hold": 16,
    "period": "2021-08-01",
    "sell": 1,
    "strongBuy": 8,
    "strongSell": 0
}]
```

I am trying to render a pie chart for each object in the array, but I cant seem to get the data flow correctly to my pie charts. I only want "Strong Sell", "Sell", "Hold", "Buy", and "Strong Buy" information on each pie chart.

I have tried the below codes, and attached screenshots showing the HTML and the pie charts

```
    var margin = 20, width = 250, height = 250
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

    var new_data = tickers.map(function(d){
        if (d){
            var temp = {"Strong Sell": d.strongSell, "Sell": d.sell, "Hold": d.hold, "Buy": d.buy, "Strong Buy": d.strongBuy}
        } else {
            var temp = {"Strong Sell": 0, "Sell": 0, "Hold": 0, "Buy": 0, "Strong Buy": 0}
        }
        return temp
    })

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["Strong Sell", "Sell", "Hold", "Buy", "Strong Buy"])
        .range(["#570e00", "#ff2a00", "#ffff00", "#00ff08", "#00570c"])

    var pie = d3.pie()
        .value(function(d) {return d.value; })

    var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(new_data))

    var recommendSvg = d3.selectAll(".company-recommend")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    recommendSvg
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
            .attr('d', d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(0)
                .outerRadius(radius)
            )
            .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
            .style("opacity", 0.7)
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

[Locations where I want pie charts to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnIe4.png)

[HTML in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8PhW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example, which assumes that the "company-recommend" divs are already created.

I've modified your code so that you don't need to use `d3.entries`. I put the data in that format from the start. In addition, I've updated `recommendSvg` so that the `data` array is bound to it. This means that each div is bound to one element in the `data` array. When drawing the pie chart in each group, we then pass the data for that chart to the `pie` generator and create one path for each slice.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="company-container">
            <div class="company-profile"></div>
            <div class="company-recommend"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="company-container">
            <div class="company-profile"></div>
            <div class="company-recommend"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            const tickers = [
                {
                    "symbol": "GME",
                    "buy": 0,
                    "hold": 3,
                    "period": "2021-08-01",
                    "sell": 5,
                    "strongBuy": 0,
                    "strongSell": 2
                },
                {
                    "symbol": "AMD",
                    "buy": 21,
                    "hold": 16,
                    "period": "2021-08-01",
                    "sell": 1,
                    "strongBuy": 8,
                    "strongSell": 0
                }
            ];

            const margin = 20;
            const width = 250;
            const height = 250;
            const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

            const data = tickers.map(d => [
                { key: 'Strong Sell', value: d.strongSell },
                { key: 'Sell', value: d.sell },
                { key: 'Hold', value: d.hold },
                { key: 'Buy', value: d.buy },
                { key: 'Strong Buy', value: d.strongBuy },
            ]);

            const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                .domain(["Strong Sell", "Sell", "Hold", "Buy", "Strong Buy"])
                .range(["#570e00", "#ff2a00", "#ffff00", "#00ff08", "#00570c"]);

            const pie = d3.pie().value(d => d.value);

            const arc = d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(0)
                .outerRadius(radius);

            // bind our data to the divs. add a group to each div.
            const recommendSvg = d3.selectAll('.company-recommend')
                .data(data)
                .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height)
                .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

            // draw the pie chart in each group
            // by creating one path for each slice
            recommendSvg.selectAll('path')
                .data(d => pie(d))
                .join('path')
                    .attr('d', arc)
                    .attr('fill', d => color(d.data.key))
                    .attr('stroke', 'black')
                    .attr('stroke-width', '2px')
                    .attr('opacity', 0.7);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, that works out perfectly. I will have to read more on how to bind the data like you did there. Once again thanks!

Comment: Hi Dan, I am stuck on another problem to display some D3 line graph, would you be kindly take a look at my new question below and offer me your expertise on D3?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68779019/d3-how-to-create-multiple-line-charts-from-an-array-of-objects